# Ajax and ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome

Hi have a page with some Ajax calls, but some requests the browser returns ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT.

I don't know if i'm doing a lot of requests or if this error can be fired by other kind of problem.

It strange because this happen in some machines and others no.

What the cause of this problem?

Lot of thanks

Answer (score 2):

It usually occurs when your session time expired . If you have kept open your application without any activity on it for longer time then session get expired for the application .

Solution : Log in Again . For better UX write some code for identifying the error code and in response alert some messages to user .

If your problem is not getting solved by this method . I have found a Google forum with same issues same discuss. 
here is the link https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/kPkVzx_HQWI

Comment: Hyperlink broken.

Answer (score 0):

That means that your server request take too much time and so your browser timed-out the connection.

I don't think it's a problem from the client side, but optimisation to do on the server side, break the big operations in smaller pieces in a way you can have all the data you need